# Schema getColumnType nort working

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5, schema

Trying to get Column type in my json (laravel project), but not working ?, can anyone se whats wrong?

```
protected function getType()
    {
      return Schema::getColumnType($this->builder->getModel()->getTable() , $this->getUpdatableColums());
    }
    enter code here
    protected function getRecords(Request $request)
    {
      //   return $this->builder->limit($request->limit)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get($this->getDisplayableColums());
      return $this->builder
            ->limit($request->limit)
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->get($this->getDisplayableColums())
            ->getType();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your getType method you seem to be passing an array instead of a string

```
protected function getType()
{
  return Schema::getColumnType($this->builder->getModel()->getTable() , $this->getUpdatableColums());
}
```

The laravel 5.5 docs say "string getColumnType(string $table, string $column)"

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_getColumnType

You might be able to change your getType method to expect a column name. And do a loop in your code

```
foreach ($this->getUpdatableColumns() as $column) {
    $this->getType($column);
}
```